# Signing apps which are already signed via Google Play Signing locally

Tags: android, google-play, signing

Currently, I'm programming a game for Android. I already published some first beta versions of it on the Google Play Store and signed it there via the Google Play App Signing. Now I want to integrate the Google Play Games Service into the app. For that, I used again the Google Play Console to create some leaderboards etc.

I set up all the configuration in the app, for example, the signing via Google Play Games. Now when I try the app, I can not test the signing while I'm in the debug or release APK, which was generated by my computer.

Now my question is, how can I sign the app with the App Signing Key stored in the Google Play Console to test the Google Play Games Services without having to upload the app every time?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sign it with the key in the Play console without uploading it.

What you can do however is enable two API signing keys for your game in the [Client Id settings](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) - your Play signing key and your local debug signing key.

As it says on that page: "You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint. Make sure to use the same package name for both. This allows Google Play games services to recognize calls from your linked APKs that are signed with either certificate. "

Comment: I have created two client IDs, first with release certificate (App signing certificate SHA-1 ) and another with debug certificate generated by Android studio. Still I am unable to sign in to games service .. and getting com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 4: 4: exception

Comment: One thing you might find useful, which happened since I first answered this question: Google has released "internal test tracks". This allows republishing test versions of you app within seconds. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213